# Ruby: Increasing Efficiency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, optimization, benchmarking

I am dealing with a large quantity of data and I'm worried about the efficiency of my operations at-scale. After benchmarking, the average time to execute this string of code is about 0.004sec. The goal of this line of code is to find the difference between the two values in each array location. In a previous operation, 111.111 was loaded into the arrays in locations which contained invalid data. Due to some weird time domain issues, I needed to do this because I couldn't just remove the values and I needed some distinguishable placeholder. I could probably use 'nil' here instead. Anyways, back to the explanation. This line of code checks to ensure neither array has this 111.111 placeholder in the current location. If the values are valid then I perform the mathematical operation, otherwise I want to delete the values (or at least exclude them from the new array to which I'm writing). I accomplished this by place a 'nil' in that location and then compacting the array afterwards.

The time of 0.004sec for 4000 data points in each array isn't terrible but this line of code is executed 25M times. I'm hoping someone might be able to offer some insight into how I might optimize this line of code.

```
temp_row = row_1.zip(row_2).map do |x, y| 
  x == 111.111 || y == 111.111 ? nil : (x - y).abs 
end.compact
```

Comment: `zip` is totally not needed here.

Comment: And yeah, 4000% improvement from creating 5000 threads - that's fantasy :)

Comment: Without zip: http://pastie.org/10881223

Answer (score 2):

You are wasting CPU generating `nil` in the ternary statement, then using `compact` to remove them. Instead, use `reject` or `select` to find elements not containing `111.111` then `map` or something similar.

Instead of:

```
row_1 = [1, 111.111, 2]
row_2 = [2, 111.111, 4]

temp_row = row_1.zip(row_2).map do |x, y| 
  x == 111.111 || y == 111.111 ? nil : (x - y).abs 
end.compact
temp_row # => [1, 2]
```

I'd start with:

```
temp_row = row_1.zip(row_2)
                .reject{ |x,y| x == 111.111 || y == 111.111 }
                .map{ |x,y| (x - y).abs }
temp_row # => [1, 2]
```

Or:

```
temp_row = row_1.zip(row_2)
                .each_with_object([]) { |(x,y), ary|
                  ary << (x - y).abs unless (x == 111.111 || y == 111.111)
                }
temp_row # => [1, 2]
```

Benchmarking different size arrays shows good things to know:

```
require 'benchmark'

DECIMAL_SHIFT = 100
DATA_ARRAY = (1 .. 1000).to_a
ROW_1 = (DATA_ARRAY + [111.111]).shuffle
ROW_2 = (DATA_ARRAY.map{ |i| i * 2 } + [111.111]).shuffle

Benchmark.bm(16) do |b|
  b.report('ternary:') do
    DECIMAL_SHIFT.times do
      ROW_1.zip(ROW_2).map do |x, y| 
        x == 111.111 || y == 111.111 ? nil : (x - y).abs 
      end.compact
    end
  end

  b.report('reject:') do
    DECIMAL_SHIFT.times do
      ROW_1.zip(ROW_2).reject{ |x,y| x == 111.111 || y == 111.111 }.map{ |x,y| (x - y).abs }
    end
  end

  b.report('each_with_index:') do
    DECIMAL_SHIFT.times do
      ROW_1.zip(ROW_2)
           .each_with_object([]) { |(x,y), ary|
             ary += [(x - y).abs] unless (x == 111.111 || y == 111.111)
           }
    end
  end
end

# >>                        user     system      total        real
# >> ternary:           0.240000   0.000000   0.240000 (  0.244476)
# >> reject:            0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.058842)
# >> each_with_index:   0.350000   0.000000   0.350000 (  0.349363)
```

Adjust the size of `DECIMAL_SHIFT` and `DATA_ARRAY` and the placement of `111.111` and see what happens to get an idea of what expressions work best for your data size and structure and fine-tune the code as necessary.

Comment: Using 'nil' and 'compact' yielded an execution time of 0.000867sec while using 'reject' yielded an execution time of 0.001219sec. These were executed on arrays of about 4000 points.

Comment: Benchmarking results that low make me suspicious. Without usable sample data and the benchmark code we can't really compare apples to apples.

Comment: I also ran it for 2000 iterations and benchmarked the full loop. The results were 8.922337sec and 10.834802sec respectively. I understand it's a bit tricky without me providing sample data. I do appreciate all of the help on this though.

Comment: It's tricky because there's missing code and data, forcing us to have to invent stuff, which results in inaccurate assumptions and broad answers. Broad questions and answers are not on-topic, nor do they help you that much, and they help those looking for similar solutions in the future even less, which is why SO exists. Those are things to keep in mind.

Comment: My intentions were most definitely not to waste the time of this community. I appreciate all of the help and time commitment that members contribute. I didn't realize that the data stored in my arrays would shape the solutions so much. I was hoping there was an obvious solution I was missing. I unfortunately cannot provide the data which composes the arrays nor would any additional code. Again, I do appreciate all of the contributions and I will keep the community principles in mind next time I pose a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `parallel` gem https://github.com/grosser/parallel and run it on multiple threads

Comment: Ah, this is definitely a very useful looking gem but it doesn't appear to be supported on ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32].

Comment: @srm985 That's a shame

Comment: Running in multiple threads won't necessarily speed things up, and could actually slow them down, especially when too many threads are used. There's a happy balance and testing will find it.